# Occupancy of a B+ Tree

Tags: data-structures, database-theory

If a B+ tree has an occupancy of 67%, does that mean the tree holds all of an index, and has additional empty nodes taking up the remaining 1/3rd?

Answer (score 2):

B+ trees, like all B-tree variants, are typically page-structured. A page size is chosen (which is a multiple of the disk page size and the CPU's page size). Each node or leaf is a page in size. Organising the tree this way eliminates *external* fragmentation.

We pay for it with *internal* fragmentation.

Each node and leaf can have a variable amount of data stored inside it. So for if a node is not full, some of that page is unused. When we say that a B+ tree has 67% occupancy, this means that 1/3 of the allocated space is unused memory at the end of pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a B* tree rather than a B+ tree. In general, for a B+ tree of order $d$, each node except the root is required to contain $m$ entries such that $d \leq m \leq 2d$. That is, each node except the root has a maximum capacity $2d$ and has to contain at least $d$ entries. Therefore, the occupancy of a B+ tree in general is at least $m / 2d \geq d / 2d = 50\%$. However, for a B* tree, it requires that each internal node to be at least $2/3$ full rather than $50\%$.